# Pegar o valor de um input com javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou fazendo uma tabela dinâmica onde os dados vem do banco de dados, e o usuário tem  a possibilidade de editar esse dados. Esses dados que vem do banco ficam dentro de `<div>`.

Ao lado desses dados tem um botão `Editar` onde ele muda a tag `<div>` por um `<input>`, e aparece um outro botao `Salvar`, até aqui tudo certo.

Só que que quando clico em salvar ele chama uma função, onde ele pega o `value` deste `<input>`para atualizar, só que ele esta pegando o valo antigo e não o novo.

Quero saber como pegar este novo dado que o usuário digitou.

Aqui esta o código:

```
function Editar(){
    //armazena o elemento div em uma variavel
    var data = document.getElementById('data');
    //muda a div para um campo, onde o usuario digita uma nova data
    data.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='data' value='" + data.innerHTML +"' id='dataVal'>";
    //armazena a data digitada na variavel
    dataVal = document.getElementById('dataVal').value;
}

function Salvar(){
    console.log(dataVal);
}
```

Então ao invés dele me dar a nova data, ele retorna a data antiga.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sua variável `dataVal` parece-me estar no escopo global, pois não a vejo a ser declarada. Seria melhor evitar isso.

O seu problema aqui é que `dataVal = document.getElementById('dataVal').value;` guarda o valor desse input no momento. Ou seja, `dataVal` é uma variável que guarda um valor estático, o que você quer é eventualmente guardar uma referência (um apontador) para o elemento, ou seja somente: `dataVal = document.getElementById('dataVal');`.

Na sua primeira função *Editar* ( e note que por norma escreve-se funções com letra pequena e Classes com letra grande) você podia tirar a ultima linha.

A minha sugestão de código seria:

```
function editar(){  // com "e" pequeno para seguir as boas práticas
    //armazena o elemento div em uma variavel
    var data = document.getElementById('data');
    //muda a div para um campo, onde o usuario digita uma nova data
    data.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='data' value='" + data.innerHTML +"' id='dataVal'>";
}

function salvar(){  // "s" pequeno
    // busca a data digitada na variavel
    var dataVal = document.getElementById('dataVal').value;
    console.log(dataVal);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Na função de *Salvar* tenta colocar:

```
     document.getElementById('dataVal').value;
```

No lugar da variável.